# Slack scopes and bot users

Tags: slack-api

I'm writing an internal app that uses the Slack python client. I'm authenticating via a bot user and trying to call the `users.lookupByEmail()` method to get Slack info for a particular user:

```
sc = SlackClient(SLACK_TOKEN)
user = sc.api_call(method='users.lookupByEmail', email=email)
```

However I get back the following:

```
'{"ok":false,"error":"missing_scope","needed":"users:read.email","provided":"identify,read,post,client,apps"}'
```

According to the API documentation (https://api.slack.com/methods/users.lookupByEmail), bot users should have access to this method. So I'm guessing my bot does not have the `users:read.email` scope. Is there anyway to add that? As a workaround I'm calling the `users.list()` method and just iterating through that but that's very inefficient with the hundreds of users we have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need the `users:read.email` scope.

Just re-authenticate your Slack app and include that scope and it should work.

However, if you used a bot custom integration you do not have the ability to add more scopes. I then recommend to create a Slack app instead, which you can do on [this page](https://api.slack.com/slack-apps) by clicking on "Create a Slack app".

Keep in mind that Slack apps need to be installed to your workspace to work. You can do that from the configuration page of your app.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "re-authenticate your Slack app". Maybe I shouldn't have used the word "app". I just feed my script the API Token for the bot that I'm using (under Browse Apps --> Custom Integrations --> Bots --> MyBot). I don't see anywhere where I can change/include a scope.

Comment: I see what you mean. I will extend my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can add scopes (permissions) in the Slack application admin pages. Under Basic Information,

1. Go to Add features & functionality and choose the Permissions subsection.
2. On the OAuth & Permissions page, scroll down to Scopes -> Permission Scopes
3. In the "Add permission by scope or API method..." dropdown, scroll to "View email addresses of people on this workspace" and select users:read.email